# Can't change password without knowing current password (even as root)

Tags: linux, opensuse, passwd, nis

So I'm using OpenSuse, and have NIS set up with 2 clients (one opensuse and one centos). When trying to change a user password, you must include the current password. Even as root, on the nis server, it asks for the users current password. Is there something I am missing here?

This isn't a huge deal (It's for class purposes) I'm just really confused about why it's doing it.

Comment: How precisely are you trying as root to change the user's password?

Comment: Logged in as root, through a console typing passwd username, at first I was trying sudo, then tried actually logging in AS root and doing it. Same thing each time.

Answer (score 1):

it's not recommended to use `passwd` as root to change users' passwords on the NIS server. 
You have to use `yppasswd`. This command requires the root password to change a user's password. this is used to add a bit of security (you must be the Nis admin).

Comment: When using yppasswd it gives the message "yppasswd is deprecated, use /usr/bin/passwd instead" and then it uses the passwd command anyways.

Comment: Ok, then think about moving to LDAP (the new hotness for replacing NIS). It's easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks, we were using it for class. It just confused me that it did this!